# Arithmetic Overflow

Tags: numbers, overflow, math, signed

Why is it that an arithmetic overflow cannot occur when adding an positive and a negative number using two's complement. If you could please provide an example with 8-bit signed integers (bytes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ... kind of sounds like homework.  Did you mean to use the 'homework' tag?

The reason you can't overflow is because adding a positive `x` and a negative number `y` will produce a value `z` such that `abs(z) < abs(x)` and `abs(z) < abs(y)`.  Since `x` and `y` could be represented without overflow, and `z` is **closer** to zero than either one, `z` can also be represented without overflow.

Any pair of positive and negative numbers form an example.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what I was looking for. And no, this is not homework, I am writing an 8086 emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you have a positive number `A`, and a negative number `B`. Their sum is `S`. Then:

```
S <= A && S >= B
```

Their sum would be somewhere in the middle. Note that there would be a carry, but that is not an overflow(incorrect sum).